# extracting word from named vector in r through a variable

Tags: r

I want to extract a specific word from a named vector having set of two words.

```
freq= c(23,34,45,21)
names(freq) = c("good boy", "bad boy","good car","car good") 
freq
```

I want all those words starting with good. The following works but i want to pass good in a variable t and then extract it by passing that variable but it's not working.
How to tell r that t is a variable and not a character in itself

```
# it works  
freq[grep("^good",names(freq))]   
# passing in a variable
t <- "good"
freq[grep("^t",names(freq))]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `paste` to build the regex to be used in `grep`:

```
term <- "good"
freq[grep(paste0("^", term), names(freq))]

good boy good car 
      23       45
```

**Data:**

```
freq <- c(23,34,45,21)
names(freq) <- c("good boy", "bad boy","good car","car good")
```

Answer (score 0):

A non-regex solution would be to use  `startsWith`

```
term <- "good"
freq[startsWith(names(freq), term)]
#good boy good car 
#      23       45
```